# filling forms, get input name with getElementInfo

Tags: casperjs

I try to get dinamicaly the name of the fields and then it fails. It works if I write the name between quotes.

```
var elms = this.getElementsInfo('select');
var name1 = elms[0].attributes.name;
var name2 = elms[1].attributes.name;
utils.dump(name1); // "tb|2564"
utils.dump(name2); // "tb|19"
```

This works:

```
this.fill('form#tbsa', {
    "tb|2564": 10,
    "tb|19": 15
}, true);
```

This fails:

```
this.fill('form#tbsa', {
    name1: 10,
    name2: 15
}, true);
```

Anybody knows why?
Thanks,
- Albin

Comment: Because with the second statement you are setting the values of the porperties `name1` and `name2` of the object, not as you intended. This behavior is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in the way you do at the moment, because this will set the values of the properties `name1` and `name2`.

If you want to to it by the parameter names in a variable you have to create the object first.

This would be following code:

```
var foo = {};
foo[name1] = 10;
foo[name2] = 15;
this.fill('form#tbsa', foo, true);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works.

Now I see the problem, it took "name1" as the name of the property, not as a variable. I thinks I never had this problem before.